# Controlling when the Static Constructor is called

Tags: c#, attributes, static-constructor

In my custom attribute's static constructor, I search the loaded assembly for all classes decorated with my attribute and perform some action on them.

**I would like the static constructor to be called as soon as possible during runtime, preferably before execution of the `static void Main()` entry point.**

Currently it only gets called after I make some call to the attribute. I *could* make such a call elsewhere in my program, but ideally the attribute's functionality would be self-contained.

Looking for answers, I read this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.

But surely there is some tricky, sly, or mischievous workaround to get a static constructor to be called ASAP. Perhaps an attribute, reflection, or some other kind of magic could be used. **Can it be done?**

*Because people would undoubtedly tell me that there is no good reason to do what I ask, I present my purpose and my code: I am trying to use attributes to declaratively configure a [db4o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o) factory. If my attribute's static constructor is called after I've already established a connection, then it has no effect and is useless. Therefore it must be called before my program gets a chance to establish such a connection.*

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CascadeOnUpdateAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Flag { get; private set; }

    public CascadeOnUpdateAttribute() : this(true) { }

    public CascadeOnUpdateAttribute(bool flag)
    {
        Flag = flag;
    }

    static CascadeOnUpdateAttribute()
    {
        var targets = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
          from type in assembly.GetTypes()
          from attribute in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CascadeOnUpdateAttribute), false).Cast<CascadeOnUpdateAttribute>()
          select new { Type = type, Cascade = attribute.Flag };

        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            Db4oFactory.Configure().ObjectClass(target.Type).CascadeOnUpdate(target.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update:

I ended up using an abstract attribute with a static method. This way I can derive as many attributes as I like and they will all be applied to a specified config by calling this one method.

```
public abstract class Db4oAttribute : Attribute
{
    public abstract void Configure(IConfiguration config, Type type);

    public static void ApplyAttributes(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var targets = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
          from type in assembly.GetTypes()
          from attribute in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Db4oAttribute), false).Cast<Db4oAttribute>()
          select new { Type = type, Attribute = attribute };

        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            target.Attribute.Configure(config, target.Type);
        }
    }
}
```

And the call site:

```
Db4oAttribute.ApplyAttributes(Db4oFactory.Configure());
_db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile("Test.db4o");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marc says, I would do it explicitly in `Main` if I were you.

You *can* invoke the type initializer for a type explicitly using the [`Type.TypeInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.typeinitializer.aspx) property and invoking it. However, this will cause it to run again *even if it's already been run* which could produce unexpected results.

I would personally move that code out of the static initializer completely. It's configuration code - why not just make it a static method which you can call explicitly? I'm not even sure I'd have it in the attribute class itself, but at least explicitly calling:

```
CascadeOnUpdateAttribute.ConfigureDb4oFactories();
```

is clearer than calling a dummy method or forcing type initialization some other way, just to get a side effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the static constructor to get called, then add a dummy method to the type and simply call it at the start of your code (`Main` etc); if it is a trivial / empty method you might want to mark it for no inlining etc.

```
class SomeType {
    static SomeType() {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeType.cctor");
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static void Init() { }
}

static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        SomeType.Init();
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}
```

You *can* use reflection to call the static constructor, but I don't recommend it; if you use reflection you can actually call the .cctor multiple times, and that is *never* a good thing...

Comment: Why would be so bad if Init gets inlined?

Comment: If it is inlined to nothing, it makes me wonder: is it called; and if it isn't called - is the .cctor invoked?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the static dummy method by calling

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(CascadeOnUpdateAttribute).TypeHandle)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of the static constructor smells; I would consider refactoring your code to control access to the db4o factory so that you don't need to use it.

Comment: I won't argue about the smell, but it would still be interesting to know about ways to get the constructor called sooner.